# Deploy a React Project on GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am pretty new to this...
i have watched  the following tutorial to deploy a react project on GitHub Pages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9n2mLqXFpU
and as I would say, I worked through all the steps exactly the same way... but still my project won't is not uploaded... can anyone tell me why??

link to the GitHub page:
http://anitakath.github.io/myPlaylist

link to the repo:
https://github.com/anitakath/myPlaylist

thank you :)

hey, I am pretty new to this...
i have watched  the following tutorial to deploy a react project on GitHub Pages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9n2mLqXFpU
and as I would say, I worked through all the steps exactly the same way... but still my project won't is not uploaded... can anyone tell me why??

link to the GitHub page:
http://anitakath.github.io/myPlaylist

link to the repo:
https://github.com/anitakath/myPlaylist